# "Performances by" or "performances from"?

Tags: prepositions

When talking about movies and acting, for example, should you write: "... great performances BY (insert actors)" or "... great performances FROM (insert actors)"?

Or are both ways correct?

Answer (score 1):

I would always say "by" myself.

However, one hears plenty of people say "from". In particular, there's a construction that suggests a "giving" or rendering of the performance:

> That was a great performance by Mae West.

> We had a great performance from Mae West.

The second one suggests that we've received something through her performance.

Answer (score 0):

They are both correct. I do not believe there is any difference in meaning either.